# Slider not sliding accurately when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently having an issue on trying to make the slider slide accurately when resizing. The responsive slider works properly when I refresh browser, only then it sets the proper values. But when I resize or shrink the browser window it doesn't seem to slide accurately. It gives a small offset

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var sliderContainer = $('.slider-container');

 var slider = $('.slider-container .slider');
 var sliderItems = $('.slider-container .slider li');

 var count = sliderItems.length;


    function responsiveCarousel() {


      var sliderContainerWidth = sliderContainer.width();

     //Set Slider Items Width
  sliderItems.width( sliderContainerWidth / 4 );

     // Set Slider Wrapper Width
  // $('.slider-container ul.slider').children().each(function() {
     //        sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
     //        slider.width( sliderWidth + 200 );
  // });

  // Set slider by 'X' number of slides

  slider.width( count*sliderContainerWidth );


  //Offset Left
  var sliderItemsWidth = sliderItems.outerWidth(true);
  var leftIndent = parseInt($(sliderItems).css('left')) - sliderItemsWidth;

  //Prepend Last Item
  slider.prepend( $('.slider-container .slider li:last') );

  slider.css({'left' : '-' + sliderItemsWidth + 'px' });

    
  $('.btns .next').on('click', function() {

   var move = parseInt($('.slider-container .slider').css('left')) - sliderItemsWidth;
 

   function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.slider-container .slider:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.slider-container .slider').append( $('.slider-container .slider li:first') );
        $('.slider-container .slider').css({ 'left' : '-' + sliderItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
        }
       });
   }

   animate( 4, 100 );
  });

  $('.btns .prev').on('click', function() {
      var move = parseInt($('.slider-container .slider').css('left')) + sliderItemsWidth;

      function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.slider-container .slider:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.slider-container .slider').prepend( $('.slider-container .slider li:last') );
        $('.slider-container .slider').css({ 'left' : '-' + sliderItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed  );
        }
       })
      }

      animate( 4, 100 );

  })


 }

 responsiveCarousel();





 $(window).resize(function() {
  responsiveCarousel();
 })



})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


.wrapper {
    max-width : 1280px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding : 0 20px;

}


.timeline-container {
    max-width : 720px;
    background-color : beige;
    margin : 0 auto;
}


.timeline-slider {
    width : 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
}


.slider {
    overflow : hidden;
    position : relative;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            transition: all 0.3s linear
}


.slider li {
    float : left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="slider-container">
     <ul class="slider">
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>

     </ul>

     <ul class="btns">
         <li class="prev">prev</li>
         <li class="next">next</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code "slider.prepend($('.slider-container .slider li:last'));" out of the function responsiveCarousel.